# How do I convert .blend and .x3d files online in PHP or Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, perl, 3d

Can I convert somehow .blend and .x3d and other 3D file sdirectly online on my own server in Javascript / PHP / Perl (own CGIs?) ?

Are there already any good librarys for this?

Did not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting .blend files directly in PHP doesnt work. But we can convert the xml-structured .x3d file easily.

Also we can convert them directly in blender.